# Are "ergnomic" keyboards good for you?

Tags: keyboard, ergonomics

I currently own the Logitech Classic Keyboard 200 USB Keyboard:

[image]

It is pretty comfortable, keys are soft, pretty standard layout.
Only problem is that sometimes it feels like my fingers get a little cramped (only when I think about it).

Is getting an ergonomic keyboard a wise thing to do to maintain good hand-health for the future (10-20 years)? Or is it just a marketing scheme to make more expensive keyboards with no real health benefit?

The keyboard I had in mind is the Logitech Split Keyboard:

[image]

I played around with the Microsoft Natural but the space button seems flawed and I generally dislike the quality on Microsoft products.

Comment: I find it highly unlikely that someone will come up with anything other than their own opinion. For what it's worth: I love the Logitech one, but you have to get used to typing on it...

Answer (score 2):

I found that you either love it or hate it. Personally I hate it. Split keyboards might be best ergonomically, but I haven't had any issues at all and much prefer a flat keyboard layout.

Comment: Also to note that ergonomically correct keyboards are more meant for carpel tunnel, not for fingers.